# How do I use Get-MailboxFolderPermission with an Office365 Group?

Tags: exchange, powershell, microsoft-office-365, office365

I'm trying to figure out how to use Get-MailboxFolderPermission for an Office365 group when connnected via powershell.

If I run:

```
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity groupname | ft Name, Identity, folderpath, foldertype
```

I see (among others) a folder named Calendar with identity groupname\Calendar, path /Calendar, and type Calendar.

When I try to view this calendar via:

```
Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity groupname:\calendar
```

it tells me the specified mailbox "groupname" doesn't exist.

I've also tried specifying the identity as domain\groupname:\calendar and as groupname@domain:\calendar. I imagine I have to specify the identity differently but all three formats work fine with usernames and Get-MailboxFolderPermission. Get-MailboxFolderStatistics accepts both user and group names in all three formats.

How do I use Get-MailboxFolderPermissions to view the calendar that Get-MailboxStatistics says exists?

Comment: When you say "group", do you mean Distribution Group? A distribution group isn't a mailbox and doesn't have folders, so I'm not sure how the Get-MailboxFolderStatistics command worked at all. Unless there's *also* a mailbox with a similar name.

Comment: Exchange Admin Center lists it with "Office 365 Group" in the "Group Type" column. Distribution Groups have "Distribution Group" in that type column. I'm not sure exactly how the group types differ but Get-MailboxFolderStatistics consistently succeeds for groups w/ type "Office365 Group" and consistently fails with "couldn't find groupname as a receipient" for groups w/ type "Distribution Group".

Comment: Aha, that's right. There's a new group type that is only available on Office 365. Instead of "-Identity" on the Get-MailboxFolderPermission try "-GroupMailbox". I've never done this before but a couple web searches turned up that parameter. See: https://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/1525/folder-permissions-for-groups-and-getting-them-recursively

Comment: Scroll to the bottom [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn641234(v=exchg.160).aspx) to see a list of new "UnifiedGroup" commandlets. Apparently in PS commandlets, "UnifiedGroup" is the name for Office 365 groups.

Comment: Hmm. Since Set-MailboxFolderPermission doesn't understand the -GroupMailbox switch it looks like I can't manage access rights very well via PS. The UnifiedGroup cmdlets look like they could add users to the group which would give them Editor access but I don't see a way to grant additional people just Reviewer access.

Comment: Weird. Is there at least a GUI way to manage permissions in the EAC?

Comment: Not that I can tell. AFAIK EAC doesn't have a GUI for managing calendar mailbox permission at all and the normal way of adjusting another user's calendar's permission is via PS. I can adjust group membership but that'll give people edit access instead of just viewing. I tried making myself an owner of the group in EAC then opening the calendar in desktop Outlook to see if I could manage things that way but so far it's saying permission denied. Sometimes with EAC changes take a little while to fully go into effect though.

Answer (score 0):

To understand why this works with your `"Office 365"` groups and fails with a `"Distribution Group"` (Also called a `Distribution List` now) you need to first understand the difference between the two.

**[Office 365 Groups](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-about-office-365-groups-b565caa1-5c40-40ef-9915-60fdb2d97fa2)**
This is one of the newer features in Office 365. This basically combines a few features and is also used by Microsoft teams. An Office 365 group has its own Mailbox, so when you use the command on an Office 365 group it will return the MailboxFolderPermission for this groups mailbox, not people who are a member and uses this Office 365 Group.

**Distribution Group**
A distribution group is a list of recipients that you wish to receive email.
A distribution group has an email alias, but no mailbox, when you send email to a group, it sends the email on to all members of the group.

**The soulution**
If you want to get the statistics for each member of a Distribution Group, you need to get the mailbox of all members of your distribution group, then pipe that to your folder statistics command.